# It's getting harder and harder not to offend anyone

Tags: logical-deduction, story

Andy, Bob and Chuck are old friends meeting for the first time in years.

**Scene 1: At the intersection**

> **ANDY**: Hey guys! Long time no see!
>   **BOB**: Hey, nice to see you, Andy! Have you seen Chuck? Is he coming?
>   **ANDY**: There he is, just about to cross the street.
>   **BOB**: Dude. Language.
>   **ANDY**: Oh right, sorry. I had forgotten about that. Hey, Chuck!
>   **CHUCK**: Hey guys! Ready to head to the restaurant?
>   **ANDY**: Hey, watch your language, Chuck.
>   **CHUCK**: Oh, I'm sorry. It's been so long, you guys!

**Scene 2: In the restaurant**

> **BOB**: Did you guys catch the soccer game last night?
>   **ANDY**: Yeah, it was pretty crazy.
>   **CHUCK**: I'm more of a hockey guy myself, I don't really follow football.
>   **ANDY**: Language, Chuck.
>   **CHUCK**: Oh man. Sorry! I keep forgetting.
>   **ANDY**: Don't worry, I have faith you're not doing it on purpose. Just be careful, okay?
>   **BOB**: Wow, Andy. You kiss your mother with that mouth?
>   **ANDY**: Seriously, Bob? Watch the language.
>   **BOB**: Oh right. I apologize. It was just a slip of, um, it just slipped out.
>   **ANDY**: I'm sorry too, Bob. I didn't mean to offend you.

**Scene 3: At the bar**

> **ANDY**: Let's get drinks!
>   **BOB**: *(reading the drink menu)* Hmm, Cointreau? What's that?
>   **BARTENDER**: It's a French fruit liqueur. An orange-flavoured spirit.
>   **BOB**: *(exasperated)* Can you believe this guy? Do you always use such language with customers?
>   **BARTENDER**: Huh? Look, I have no idea what you're talking about.
>   **BOB**: Forget it. Just get me a Scotch, please.
>   **ANDY**: I think I'll have the same.
>   **CHUCK**: No alcohol for me, I'm driving. I'll have a ***(censored)***, please.
>   **ANDY & BOB**: *(in unison)* Language!

What offensively named drink did Chuck order?

Comment: I struggle ih part 2 understanding what did Andy say to offend Bob?!

Comment: Andy and Bob need to fix their ideas of offensive language.

Comment: Bob probably ordered a "friend".

Comment: This puzzle offends me  //rim shot

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think @SergeiPetunin mostly got the right answer, especially that

> Andy is offended by body part references and Bob is offended by Christianity references.

However, to overcome

> Chuck’s lack of alcohol

It’s possible that he instead ordered a

> ***Virgin*** Bloody Mary, which has the blood reference (offending Andy), as well as a Virgin Mary reference (offending Bob) and by definition contains no alcohol.

Per @HughMeyers, another delicious choice could be

> A ***Shirley Temple***, which is also a non-alcoholic beverage. Temple is both a religious reference and a body part, which would offend both Andy and Bob.

Comment: I think rot13(Fuveyrl Grzcyr) is a better drink, because I wouldn't count "blood" as a body part.

Comment: I agree, I think it definitely fits better too, @GrumpyCrouton!

Comment: Another possibility would be (ivetva juvgr ynql), or a (ivetva Zbwvgb) or even a (tebja-hc Fuveyrl Grzcyr)

Comment: Yup, this is it!

Comment: @jafe the former or latter?

Comment: @TimHallman The latter is what I intended (but of course both are valid solutions).

Answer (score 33):

I think Chuck ordered

> Bloody Mary

since Bob is offended by

> Christian references (faith, cross, spirit, in this case - Mary)

and Andy is offended by

> parts of human body (mouth, foot, head, in this case - blood)

Comment: That seems like a great guess, because rot13(Obo pngpurf uvzfrys orsber fnlvat "gbathr", xabjvat gung jbhyq bssraq Naql.) Awesome job! Only problem (may be wrong) is that rot13(oybbql znel unf ibqxn, qbrfa'g vg? Puhpu fnlf ur'f abg univat nypbuby.)

Comment: Nice. The word that Bob avoided saying at the end of scene 2 fits, too.

Comment: I like your thinking, but one thing bothers me, rot13(Oybbql znel vf n pbpgnvy pbagnvavat ibqxn, juvpu zrnaf vg pbagnvaf nypbuby. Naq Puhpx fgngrq irel pyrneyl gung 'Ab nypbuby sbe zr'.)

Comment: @NudgeNudge Yep, I think you're right, doesn't quite fit.

Comment: There's a drink named after a famous child actress with curly hair. Surely you've heard of it? (Sorry, irresistible pun.)

Comment: @HughMeyers I don't think I had. Can't quite google it either.

Comment: @HughMeyers that’s a really good suggestion!! I hadn’t even thought of that since I was focused solely on de-alcoholized beverages rather than non-alcoholic ones.

Comment: There's a popular non-alcoholic cocktail called a rot13(Fuveyrl Grzcyr). So the second word would be offensive to both.

Comment: (fuveyrl grzcyr) certainly meets all criteria.

Comment: @HughMeyers of course I've heard of it, and don't call me Shirley.

Comment: I do believe the [person] you refer to is a rather different one from the one you are referring to.   Think   HenryOctavius